# What Music could be used to reflect industry and factory work?

Tags: classical-music, electronic-music, early-music

Examples that may use mallets or other non instrumental sounds. A style like Iannis Xenakis' would be brilliant

Comment: I can I'm just looking for more examples 

Answer (score 2):

Here are starting points for some composers you might look into:

Karlheinz Stockhausen
Oktophonie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdIe2CrorMM

John Cage
First Construction (in Metal): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlBo7_3EXqk

Wintergatan
Marble Conveyor Belt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AEvQAg6TE0

Steve Reich
Music for Pieces of Wood: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4JQD0cy87I

Avraamov
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v3u2sU54Os

Also something random things I stumbled onto:

Ann Kroeber & Alan Splet
Industrial Sounds with Soul: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG23kZ0XswU

And just for fun, a personal favorite:
Don Byron, "Powerhouse": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUmAxSlBhPs

Answer (score 1):

Non-instrumental sounds are neither typically used in classical nor in early music.

I guess, repetitive or even minimal music could fit, since the striking feature of assembly line is hard time restrictions and repetitiveness.

I would recommend to consider the sound track of Charlie Chaplins "Modern Times", apparently also written by him.

A competely different approach is one of my Baroque favourites: [François Couperin: Tic-Toc-Choc](https://youtu.be/8r5kecJfS2I) (its other title *Les maillotins* seems to refer to a sort of hammers.) I enclose a second [recording](https://youtu.be/r_QwMjySegs) alone due to its presentation on a factory floor.